# Is this possible to block all requests ends with a specific url in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, security, web-services

Is this possible to block a requests ends with a specific url in apache, for example i have to block all the requests end with ?wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is easy to solve, you can use `mod_rewrite` to achieve this:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} "^wsdl.*$"
RewriteRule     "" "-" [F]
```

This will block any request with `wsdl` at the beginning of the first query parameter name.

To block only the `wsdl` parameter anywhere in the query string, the regular expression is a bit more complicated:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ".*(?:^|&)wsdl(?:=|&|$)"
RewriteRule     "" "-" [F]
```

This configuration works on

- ?wsdl
- ?wsdl=something
- ?s1=s2&wsdl
- ?s1=s2&wsdl=something
- ?s1=s2&wsdl&s3=s4

Sources I've used:

- https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could have helped.